# How to compare Date and a String in swift 3

Tags: ios, string, date, swift3, nsdateformatter

I have a `String` like this `2017-07-11T00:00:00"` and I have a `Date` like `2017-01-30 18:30:00 +0000`. How can I compare these 2?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Obtain a difference of time, in what? Minutes? Seconds? Or just say if they are different? Or greater? Lower? Did you notice all my questions marks?

Comment: @Fabien I have 2 Strings like above. I want to check given date is equal or in between day of those 2 strings

Comment: Does the Timezone indication matters? do you want to cut it out?

Comment: I don't need the timezone part specifically,, but dates should be compared correctly

Comment: If you do not have a timezone indication on the left side, or if you don't know what it is then you cannot accurately compare dates. This is a difference between a "naive" date and a timezoned date.

Comment: @Fabien How can I correctly compare it with the time zone. My string data doesn't return timezone part. What should I do?

Comment: If you do not care about being 24hours accurate, you can ignore it. If you need pinpoint accuracy, then you are in trouble , I don't know why in your context you do not have this information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149278/discussion-between-user1960169-and-fabien).